# This method must return a result of type HttpResponse<String>

Tags: java

```
   public HttpResponse<String> request() {
        try {
            return HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            
        }

    }
```

How can I handle this issue? I want to handle error in this method and not throw it outside of this function, but I have to return `HttpResponse` type. How can I make it? Should I send request one more time?

It will ask me to catch it one more time I think, and I don't see any solution. I just started to learn it.

Answer (score -1):

If you'll have some exception you should return statement with type HttpResponse.
Just create HttpResponse in catch block like that:

```
    public HttpResponse<String> request() {
        try {
            return HttpClient.newHttpClient().send(request, HttpResponse.BodyHandlers.ofString());
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            new DefaultHttpResponseFactory().newHttpResponse(new BasicStatusLine(HttpVersion.HTTP_1_1, HttpStatus.SC_OK, "Reason phrase"), null);
        }

    }
```